# eclipse default folder when create file

Tags: eclipse, default

When eclipse creates a file (let's say feeds.txt), the file is automatically saved and read from eclipse folder (not workspace/project folder). How do I change it to workspace/"project name" folder

btw, i used this:

```
private static final String feedFile = " Feeds.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

what did you use that for? .. if named like that, eclipse should create a new file in the project folder
Try this

```
import java.io.*;

    try {
        File file = new File("Feeds.txt");
            file.createNewFile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/createfile.html